# How to create a new column based on existing columns that have NaN in pandas dataframe?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have data such as below in the picture with `Col1` through `Col4`. I want to make a new column based on `NaN` values (in my dataset they're `NaN`; it's just an empty cell in the picture).

The new column (highlighted in green called `scalar` is based on 2 rules. If `Col3` and `Col4` are empty, then `scalar` has a value of `1`. If `Col1` and `Col2` are empty, then scalar has a value of `2`. Else it should be `3`.

I can't seem to figure out the code to implement those rules.

[example dataset/pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RFHyh.png)

```
   Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, scalar  
1,  yes,  yes,     ,     ,      1  
2,  yes,     ,  yes,     ,      3  
3,     ,     ,  yes,  yes,      2  
4,  yes,  yes,  yes,  yes,      3  
5,  yes,     ,     ,     ,      3  
6,  yes,  yes,     ,  yes,      3
```

Comment: Please include your data as text, not images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please Check the snippet .Nested list comprehension did the work

```
import pandas as pd
data=[['yes','yes',' ',' '],
      ['yes',' ','yes',' '],
      [' ',' ','yes','yes'],
      ['yes','yes','yes','yes'],
      [ 'yes',' ' ,' ',' '],
      [ 'yes','yes',' ','yes']
    ]
df =  pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Col1',  'Col2',  'Col3',  'Col4']) 
df['Scalar'] = [2 if ((w==' 'and x==' ')and(y!=' 'and z!=' '))
                else 1 if ((y==' 'and z==' ')and(w!=' 'and x!=' '))
                else 3 for w,x,y,z in zip(df['Col1'],df['Col2'],df['Col3'],df['Col4'])]
```

```
Input
  Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4
0  yes  yes          
1  yes       yes     
2            yes  yes
3  yes  yes  yes  yes
4  yes               
5  yes  yes       yes

Output
  Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4  Scalar
0  yes  yes                 1
1  yes       yes            3
2            yes  yes       2
3  yes  yes  yes  yes       3
4  yes                      3
5  yes  yes       yes       3
```